# IE freezes displaying Bootstrap Modal from AngularJS

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i have a very simple Bootstrap modal which I want to display through AngularJS once a call to my webservice returns success. the modal popups but it freezes the IE 9+ and I have to force close it though the same code works on Firefox and Chrome.

my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel" id="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and script from angular which opens the modal.

```
SearchReq.success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.IsWorking = false;

                if (data.success) {
                    $scope.AttendedSessions = data.attendedsessions;
                    $scope.LateSessions = data.latesessions;

                    $('#modal').modal('show');
                }
                else {
                    showAlert("<strong>Failure!</strong> " + data.errormsg, "danger", 3000);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AngularUI Bootstrap https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/